# Python Regex matching already matched sub-string

Tags: python, regex

I'm fairly new to Python Regex and I'm not able to understand the following:

I'm trying to find one small letter surrounded by three capital letters.

My first problem is that the below regex is giving only one match instead of the two matches that are present `['AbAD', 'DaDD']`

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> # String
... str = 'AbADaDD'
>>> 
>>> pat = '[A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z]'
>>> regex = re.compile(pat)
>>> 
>>> print regex.findall(str)
['AbAD']
```

I guess the above is due to the fact that the last `D` in the first regex is not available for matching any more? Is there any way to turn off this kind of matching.

The second issue is the following regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> # String
... str = 'AbADaDD'
>>> 
>>> pat = '[^A-Z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][^A-Z]'
>>> regex = re.compile(pat)
>>> 
>>> print regex.findall(str)
[]
```

Basically what I want is that there shouldn't be more than three capital letters surrounding a small letter, and therefore I placed a negative match around them. But `['AbAD']` should be matched, but it is not getting matched. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mainly because of the overlapping of matches. Just put your regex inside a lookahead inorder to handle this type of overlapping matches.

```
(?=([A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z]))
```

Code:

```
>>> s = 'AbADaDD'
>>> re.findall(r'(?=([A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z]))', s)
['AbAD', 'DaDD']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eX9yA4/3)

For the 2nd one, you should use negative lookahead and lookbehind assertion like below,

```
(?=(?<![A-Z])([A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z])(?![A-Z]))
```

Code:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?=(?<![A-Z])([A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z])(?![A-Z]))', s)
['AbAD']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eX9yA4/2)

The problem with your second regex is, `[^A-Z]` consumes a character (*there isn't a character other than uppercase letter exists before first `A`*) but the negative look-behind `(?<![A-Z])` also do the same but it won't consume any character . It asserts that the match would be preceded by any but not of an uppercase letter. That;s why you won't get any match.

Comment: I get the problem with the first regex because of overlapping matches, but why is there a problem with the second regex?

Comment: @KartikAnand see the explanation at the last in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Any clues at to how to return the small letter in between that is being matched?

Comment: provide the capturing group for only the small letter inside the lookahead . See https://regex101.com/r/eX9yA4/4 and https://regex101.com/r/eX9yA4/5

Answer (score 0):

The problem with you regex is tha it is eating up the string as it progresses leaving nothing for second match.Use lookahead to make sure it does not eat up the string.

```
pat = '(?=([A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z]))'
```

For your second regex again do the same.

`print re.findall(r"(?=([A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z](?=[^A-Z])))",s)`

.For more insights see

1)After first match the string left is `aDD` as the first part has matched.

2)`aDD` does not satisfy `pat = '[A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z]'`.So it is not a part of your match.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1st issue,

You should use this pattern,

```
 r'([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1})'
```

#### Example

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'AbADaDD'
>>> re.findall(r'([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1})', str)
['AbA', 'DaD']
```

---

#### 2nd issue

You should use,

```
(?=(?<![A-Z])([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}[A-Z]{1})(?![A-Z]))
```

#### Example

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'AbADaDD'
>>> re.findall(r'(?=(?<![A-Z])([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}[A-Z]{1})(?![A-Z]))', str)
['AbAD']
```